# Animation-delay Increments in nth-child iterations

Tags: css, sass

Trying to set up an animation with multiple elements that loops through a set of 12 elements, where each child element except for the first has an animation delay of `i * 0.5`.

Is there any way I can use a SCSS for-loop, to not have to simple type out `animation-delay: X` for each of the child elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
  .yourclass:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: $i * 0.5;
  }
}
```